# How to install Spotify on Guix System?

Tags: guixsd

Given that Guix is a GNU project, it is no surprise that `guix search spotify` returns nothing. Spotify provide both Debian and Snap packages; is there a way to automatically convert one of these packages, or even the the package stream itself, to a Guix package definition? Even better, has someone alread done this?

Comment: The only way to have "spotify" on guix is by installing ncspot or spotify-tui

Answer (score 5):

I have looked for this for a while now and have not yet found any guix package definition.

The best solution i have found is to install flatpak and then use spotify through flatpak.

First install flatpak:

```
guix install flatpak
```

Then tell flatpak that you would like to use the flathub repo:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Now you can install spotify by running:

```
flatpak install com.spotify.Client
```

Then you will likely be asked if flatpak should install from the repo, accept if
it suggests flathub.
Finally, to run spotify, run the command:

```
flatpak run com.spotify.Client
```

Now spotify should be running. This is the way you will likely run it on
your computer.

Notice that although flatpak might install .desktop
files correctly, for me the case has been that the .desktop files have not
been installed in my path.

Comment: I was able to use this instruction to install software with flatpak after I added `--user` to the command adding the flatpak repo. Otherwise, it complained that it cannot access `/var/lib/flatpak`.

Comment: I was able to make GNOME show the icons by adding `export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS:$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share"
` in the beginning of `~/.bash_profile` as explained here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-guix/2019-08/msg00118.html There is an open issue for that: https://issues.guix.gnu.org/44997

Comment: It can't seem to open a browser for me to login, so it's basically useless. I'm using i3wm.