# No thumbnails in GNOME files on a Guix system

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thumbnails, guixsd

GNOME Files (Nautilus) fails to generate thumbnails on an up-to-date Guix system, which is a [known outstanding issue](https://issues.guix.gnu.org/39117). Small empty files just go to `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory`. While this is being debugged and fixed, is there another way to browse files with thumbnails being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it is possible to use Thunar instead for browsing the files. For it to generate thumbnails, Tumbler is also needed:

```
$ guix install thunar tumbler
```

Once Thunar generated thumbnails in the directories that you browse with it, those thumbnails will also show up in GNOME Files, so you are not restricted to using Thunar with this approach.

---

A better way to do this is to add `(service xfce-desktop-service-type)` to the list of operating system services. This allows to augment the environment to provide a better integrated Thunar. (See [Desktop Services](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Desktop-Services.html) section in the Guix Manual.) For example, it will remember your zoom level for thumbnails size from the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install the development version of Nautilus (`org.gnome.NautilusDevel`) with Flatpak. The Flatpak version generates thumbnails. (I used [the answer to a different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630616/423679), including comments, to setup Flatpak on Guix. Then I followed [the official guide for nightly GNOME apps](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nightly).) It will not allow you to open any files, unless you [install `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2446).